# Docker cannot read file which has been changed in PhpStorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm

Docker cannot read mounted file which has been edited in PhpStorm. It looks like this in docker:

[image]

And the `cat composer.json` shows then:

```
cat: composer.json: Input/output error
```

Sometimes `cat` helps to return file back to live.

At the same time there is no problem with Sublime usage. Therefore I guess there reason is hidden somewhere in PhpStorm setting, but which ones?

Comment: My only suspect is `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Synchronization | Use "safe write"` -- it writes into temp file first, then deleted original and renames temp file. During that it may loose owner/rights info (at very least it was in some cases in the past). try disabling that option and see how it goes.

Comment: @LazyOne please post it as an answer, seems it works. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main (and only) suspect is `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Synchronization | Use "safe write"`.

When enabled (which is by default) it writes into temp file first, then deletes original and renames temp file. When doing that the new file may loose owner/access permissions info (at very least it was in some cases in the past).

Try disabling that option and see how it goes.